# Can't drop files to IShellView when FWF_DESKTOP flag set

Tags: windows, winapi, shell

I implemented an IShellBrowser to host an IShellView object. And I set the FWF_DESKTOP flag when I call IShellView::CreateViewWindow. After IShellView::UIActivate, the view window its created cannot accept user drop files on it, but can drag to other explorer Window.
I tried to obtain an IDropTarget via IShellFolder::CreateViewObject, and RegisterDragDrop to the view window, it works. But when I drag file from explorer to it, no dragging image displayed(it seems like old style D&D), and I also can't drag and drop items in same window.
If I CreateViewWindow with FWF_NONE, all fine. But....why?

How can I make Drag & Drop work properly when I specify FWF_DESKTOP?

Answer (score 0):

The desktop view might have some special handling, even MSDN says:

> This value applies only to the desktop
>   view and is not used for typical Shell
>   folders.

Why do you think you need the FWF_DESKTOP flag?

Comment: We want our folder view to be exactly same as desktop

Comment: @user739576: Unless you have created a 3rd party shell to replace explorer, using this flag does not make any sense IMHO